# Android : Constraint layout difference between programatically vs preview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I need to layout three views as like this pictures.

[image]

Here is the respective xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <View
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:id="@+id/reference"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/reference"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/reference"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/reference"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/reference"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/up" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The expected behavior is that if the green view grows in size, then the blue and red would stick to top and bottom, respectivly, with 20dp of difference.

This works fine when designing the view in the preview, but when I try to layout the same view by code, the red and blue views collapse

```
private inline fun <T: View> constructId(constructor: (Context) -> T,
                                         context: Context,
                                         id: Int): Pair<T,Int> {
    val view = constructor(context)
    view.id = id
    return Pair(view, id)
}

---------------------------------------------------------------
val set = ConstraintSet()
val verticalMargin = intDimen(R.dimen.vertical_margin_8dp)
val verticalGuideline = R.id.pub_container_vertical_guideline
val spaceMargin = intDimen(R.dimen.horizontal_margin_2dp)
set.create(verticalGuideline, ConstraintSet.VERTICAL_GUIDELINE)
set.setGuidelinePercent(verticalGuideline, 0.5f)

val (viewLeft, leftId) = constructId(::View, context, R.id.pub_container_1)
viewLeft.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_red_dark))
set.constrainHeight(leftId, intDimen(R.dimen.vertical_icon_256dp))
set.connect(leftId, ConstraintSet.TOP, contentId, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, verticalMargin)
set.connect(separatorId, ConstraintSet.TOP, leftId, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, verticalMargin)
set.connect(
        leftId, ConstraintSet.START,
        ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, spaceMargin
)
set.connect(
        leftId, ConstraintSet.END,
        verticalGuideline, ConstraintSet.END, spaceMargin
)

val (viewUp, upId) = constructId(::View, context, R.id.pub_container_2)
val (viewBottom, bottomId) = constructId(::View, context, R.id.pub_container_3)
viewUp.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_red_dark))
viewBottom.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_red_dark))

set.connect(upId, ConstraintSet.TOP, leftId, ConstraintSet.TOP)
set.connect(upId, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, bottomId, ConstraintSet.TOP, spaceMargin)
set.connect(upId, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END)
set.connect(upId, ConstraintSet.START, verticalGuideline, ConstraintSet.START, spaceMargin)
set.constrainHeight(upId, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT)

set.connect(bottomId, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, leftId, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
set.connect(bottomId, ConstraintSet.TOP, upId, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, spaceMargin)
set.connect(bottomId, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END)
set.connect(
        bottomId, ConstraintSet.START,
        verticalGuideline, ConstraintSet.START, spaceMargin
)
set.constrainHeight(bottomId, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT)

this.addView(viewLeft)
this.addView(viewUp)
this.addView(viewBottom)
set.applyTo(this)
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Why do you want to create layout by code that can be easily done by XML ?

Comment: The idea was to define an abstract upper class by code using constraint layout, so the child classes would define a common layout and only modify its differences. This was to avoid the overhead of nesting layouts which had a performance impact on scrolling

Comment: You can use <merge> as root tag that will eliminate the unnecessary layout :-)

Comment: I know the existence of the <merge> tag but for this particular case was not possible, because the child class should be set relative to the parents layouts, which is not possible if you have merge tag

Comment: Last time I did it(ConstraintLayout) worked fine. Are you sure?

Comment: You need to have one layout for each child (one layout with merge per child), repeating the greater context wich I wanted to avoid. Also, you have to refer, at layout writting, undeclered ids. 
The idea was that you only have to modify the parent layout only in one place and not in every child class/layout. This is easily achieved in iOS and I was trying to replicate it in Android. The motivation of writing the code instead of xml was that the process of rendering needs interaction parent-child. 
Although it is a little convoluted, the question is aimed at the differences between code/xml